# Existence of a non-vanishing smooth vector field on a given set of points

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Given a set of pairwise distinct points $A=\{p_{1},p_{2}, \cdots, p_{n}\}$ on some regular surface $S$. How can we prove that there always exists some smooth vector field $\sigma:S \rightarrow TS$, such that $\sigma$ is non-vanishing with respect to $A$ (i.e, $\sigma(p_{i}) \neq 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$)?

Comment: Choose charts about each of the $p_i$ and expand to cover $S$ with charts. Choose a partition of unity subordinate to this collection of charts. Use the charts to pull constant non-zero vector fields from $\Bbb R^2$ back to the chart domains. Use the partition of unity to sum them into a vector field over all $S$.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you so much for your comment! Would you please explain a little bit more  on "pulling constant non-zero vector fields back"? I'm a little bit confused with this. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Each chart $\phi : U \to \Bbb R^2$ induces a differential map $d\phi : T_US \to T_{\phi(U)}\Bbb R^2 \cong \phi(U)\times\Bbb R^2$ which is invertible. Choose a vector $v \in \Bbb R^2$. This induces a constant vector field $$\mathbf v : \phi(U) \to \phi(U)\times\Bbb R^2 : x \mapsto (x, v)$$ So define a vector field $$\mathbf v^* : U \to T_US : p \to d\phi^{-1}(\mathbf v(\phi(p))) = d\phi^{-1}(\phi(p), v)$$

Comment: Please do not delete your questions, especially when someone has gone to the effort of commenting and/or writing an answer for you. This is quite unfriendly.